# Bulk import geotagged raster images in attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have more more than 700 points in my shapefile with name of images in attribute table. I want to add a raster field to the shapefile so that i can add all images of those points in respective field.

Adding manually is tedious.

Can you suggest a better way for me to import those geotagged raster into attribute table?

Comment: I've removed your tag for ArcPy.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Answer (score 3):

Under Data management there are some tools for attaching images. Firstly you should enable attachments than add attachments.

1- "Data management/attachments" click "Enable Attachments" or go to geodatabase and right click to the layer and choose "Manage/Create Attachments"

2- Create an excel table that stores your points ID related with filename (dont forget the extension of img)

3- Under "Data management/add attachments" you can automatically add all atachments to your dataset, you can add several images to one point or several points with one image (depending how you have related in excel sheet).

**Excel will looks like:**

[image]

**Add Attachments, field ID will create the relationship**

[image]

**Result: Check your database because arcmap has extended this feature with two other table "xxxx_ATACH" and "xxxx_ATACHREL" **

[image]

Comment: I want a raster filed rather than attachment.

Comment: Than i suggest to try the conversions between different datatypes (raster <-> blob), rather than a direct load into Raster field.

Comment: I finally got it. I loaded my rasters in raster catalogue and joined with the table raeted from "Geotagged photos to Point".

Comment: Nice one, just tested and everything worked but im just curious. How did you transferred raster into your required field? Or you hadn't any predefined structure or database.

Comment: No, didn't have any predefined field.